# JQuery popup or MS Ajax Library Modal popup?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, popup

I have a user control shows a details of a record in a grid and it is shown inside a JQuery [poup](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/).

To implement that, I suppose to make a postback to this user control and pass a value from the client holds the id of the item which I want to show its details.

I know that [ModalPopup](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx)  provids the server side functionality but actually I prefer the JQuery controls.

I wonder if you could give me your opinion about that should I use Microsoft Modal Popup or It is OK to use a JQuery client side with some effort in postbacks?

Answer (score 1):

1. I, personally, would go for a jQuery
   approach. Atleast you can be sure of
   and have a fair degree of control
   over everything that's happening
   under the hood.
2. With a little effort you can even
   fetch your records via Ajax(jQuery
   has a whole bunch of stuff in its
   Ajax API) and inject them into your
   modal window.